# Как функция strtotime разбирает переданную дату?

Tags: php, дата, время

Ребята, ситуация такая:

```
$dateFrom = "01.17"; или 02.17 или 03.17

strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00", strtotime("01.".$dateFrom));
```

На выходе я получаю почему-то текущую дату, то есть `2017-10-07 00:00:00`

Но если я напишу:

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59", strtotime("31.".$dateFrom));
```

То я получу, как и предполагаю, `2017-01-31 23:59:59`

Почему так, и как мне получить не текущую дату, а ту, которую я пишу?

Comment: Потому strtotime интерпретирует `01.01.17` как `час.минута.секунда`

Comment: Спасибо большое! действительно так..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что в определенном случае у вас это работает правильно еще не чего не значит что вы правильно задали дату для вычисления метки времени `unix`.

Есть два формата задания дат для метода `strtotime`.

Первое это американский стандарт:

> m/d/y

Второе европейский:

> d-m-y или d.m.y

И в обоих случаях нужно год задавать четырьмя цифрами.

> Обратите внимание на разделители, если что то перепутать то можете
>   получит неожиданный результат даты, или ошибку в зависимости от того
>   какую дату вы задаете (если перепутать день с месяцем).

Подробно обо всем этом можно прочитать [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php).

Поправка:

Формат ISO 8601:

> YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: https://xkcd.ru/1179/ :)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо за поправку. :)

Comment: Спасибо ребята! все сделал, все работает)